# Api Platform GraphQl API filter subresources by parent

Tags: php, graphql, api-platform.com

I am building a service which supports both RestAPI and Graphql with API Platform.

The Rest API configuration for the subresource working as expected.
For example in RestAPI following request

```
/api/intents/23/intent_economic_activities
```

returns **IntentEconomicActivities** of intent **23**.

But I don't know how to configure ApiResource to also require intentId and use it for GraphQL requests.

Here is my ApiResource configs of subResource:

```php
#[ApiResource(
    uriTemplate: '/intents/{intentId}/intent_economic_activities/{id}',
    operations: [
        new Get(),
    ],
    uriVariables: [
        'intentId' => new Link(toProperty: 'intent', fromClass: Intent::class),
        'id' => new Link(fromClass: IntentEconomicActivity::class),
    ],
    routePrefix: 'api',
    graphQlOperations: [
        new Query(),
    ],
)]
#[ApiResource(
    uriTemplate: '/intents/{intentId}/intent_economic_activities',
    operations: [
        new GetCollection(),
    ],
    uriVariables: [
        'intentId' => new Link(toProperty: 'intent', fromClass: Intent::class),
    ],
    routePrefix: 'api',
    graphQlOperations: [
        new QueryCollection(),
    ],
)]
#[ORM\Entity]
class IntentEconomicActivity
```

Issue is only when fetching a subresource collection via GraphQL.
It is working properly when fetching single subresource:

```
{
  intentEconomicActivity(id: "/api/intents/20/intent_economic_activities/6") {
    id
  }
}
```

I am using Doctrine ORM.

ApiPlatform v3.2